# Matching items in one table with their price in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, relationship

So I have a Query with a list of "Items" Say 'APPLE', 'Carrot', and 'Pear', and a field beside it called "Quantity". On a another table I have a column with a field called "Item", then beside it a field with "cost". (Thus to show the item and its cost.) What I want to do is search the list for the item then take that item and times the price by the quantity, and show it on the chart.

Let's also assume that in the table of items that some of the spelling is not exact so one person may have typed apple and another apples, but in my item column it just says Apple, how do I make sure that they will find each other or the closest match on the list?

I have done a little work and I assume I have to create a join of some sort, but I am not sure of the expression to do the paring or the prices with the items once that is done a simple multiplication expression can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that you will need to perform a JOIN between the two tables/queries to match up the rows that correspond to each other ("apples to apples", so to speak). If your first table/query was called [Orders] and your second table/query was called [Prices] then a simple query to "do the math" would be something like

```
SELECT 
    Orders.Item, 
    Orders.Quantity, 
    Prices.Price,
    Orders.Quantity * Prices.Price AS Cost
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN
    Prices
        ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
```

Regarding your point...

> Lets also assume that in the table of items that some of the spelling
>   is not exact so one person may have typed apple and another apples,
>   but in my item column it just says Apple, how do I make sure that they
>   will find each other

...the short answer is: You design your database in such a way that such discrepancies cannot occur. Use your favorite Internet search engine to do some research on the following topics:

1. Data Validation
2. Referential Integrity

### Edit re: comment

> I was just wondering if I could use a Like function with % sign of some sort to search for the closest answer to solve the [matching] problem

Generally speaking, no. Those types of approaches can be very difficult to implement reliably (think "apples" vs. "pineapples") and can be very difficult to audit if incorrect matching occurs.

If you have dirty data then you're most likely just going to have to get busy and clean it up.

Comment: OK I was just wondering if I could use a Like function with % sign of some sort to search for the closest answer to solve the problem as I am using fruit as an example but some of my combinations are say mutlti word connections like "Ford F-150" or "General Electric and Company". So when I was pulling old data into the database people did not always enter it the same way and instead of changing thousands of records I was wondering if I could make a few very similar ones that would be recognized by the rest